# Finding a basis for an eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A basis for the eigenspace of S corresponding to the eigenvalue λ=3

S= $$
        \begin{matrix}
        3 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & -1 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Augmented Matrix= $$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 4 & -2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

RREF= $$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

y=0

z=0

I know an answer is {(1,0,0)} but im not sure what the next steps would be from here.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenspace for $c$ is nullspace of $S - cI$. So for $\lambda = 3$, we write 
down
$$
S - 3I = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & -4 & 2\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The nullspace of that is given by $z = 0, y = 0, $ and $x$ is anything at all. A basis for that is $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: Dead center in the matrix $-1-3 = -4$

Comment: Fixed -- thanks! (Fortunately, no difference in the answer. :) )